# Send an specific header by ajax to flask

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, python-3.x, flask

In my flask api file (api.py) i want to get the header "USER" to connect him when he send a request. So i have this line :

```
@app.before_request
    def prepare():
        print('Step 1 : {}'.format(request.headers.get("USER")), file=sys.stdout)
        username = request.headers.get("USER")
        user = find.user_by_username(username)
        print('Step 2', file=sys.stdout)
```

On my frontend i have an ajax request to get the task of the user :

```
$.ajax({
    url : urlBackend+"weapon/"+weapon,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    headers: {
        'USER':'toto'
    },
    success : function(resu, statut){
        //I get the weapon of my user
    },

    error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
      console.log("resultat : "+dump(resultat)+"; statut : "+statut+"; erreur : "+erreur);
    },

    complete : function(resultat, statut){

    }

  });
```

My problem is that my function prepare(in file api.py) don't find the user. In my console it's don't print "Step 1 : toto Step 2" but "Step 1 : None"

Someone have an idea of what i did wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more of your code, especially where you render the template. Or how do you run the ajax call?

Comment: Sur, so first i don't render template. I just call my flask api to get some json file that I use to fill my front-end part. 
Actualy my frontend is on http://127.0.0.1:80 and my flask turn on http://127.0.0.1:5000

Next,I just run ajax at the load of the page.$( document ).ready(function() {
 viewWeapon("sword");
}); 

And the function "viewWeapon(weapon)" just have the ajax request that i put above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my problem come from the fact that when i add a header in my jquery request using "header" or "beforeSend" (for a reason that i don't know) their will be not one but 2 requests that will be send to the flask.

The first one with the request method : "OPTIONS" and a second one will be the real jquery request. But like in the first their is no header it fail and the request stop here.

So to solve this problem i add `if request.method != 'OPTIONS':` at the begin of my function prepare.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom headers for sending data for a special reason, I'd like to know.
The problem with your request is, is that you specify it as a GET request, but the method used will be OPTIONS. This is because you never send any data

If you were to change this bit:

```
headers: {
    'USER':'toto'
},
```

to:

```
data: {
    'USER':'toto'
},
```

And in your @app.before_request use:

```
print('Step 1 : {}'.format(request.args.get('USER')), file=sys.stdout)
username = request.args.get('USER')
user = find.user_by_username(username)
print('Step 2', file=sys.stdout)
```

This will actually send the data. Please let me know if this helped

Comment: I am preatty sur that if i do like this it will work but i can't tuch the python part. So i just want to find a way to send the header in my ajax request.